# Mascara para valores monetários

Tags: javascript, jquery, mask, maskmoney

Queria criar uma mascara para valores monetários, onde a pessoa iria digitando e fosse inserindo as pontuações e separações das casas decimais automaticamente. Ex:

> R$ 1
>
> R$ ,11
>
> R$ 1,10
>
> R$ 11,00
>
> R$ 110,00
>
> R$ 1.110,00

e assim por diante

Tentei utilizar jQuery.InputMask do NuGet, mas ele só serve para usar uma mascara completa

Comment: Tentou Jquery-maskMoney?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Existem vários plugins ([lista de plugins de máscara para jQuery](http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/mask/)). Para os seus requisitos o [jquery-maskMoney](http://plentz.github.io/jquery-maskmoney/) parece ser ideal:

```js
$("#meuDinheiro").maskMoney();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-maskmoney/3.0.2/jquery.maskMoney.min.js"></script>



<input type="text" id="meuDinheiro" data-thousands="." data-decimal="," data-prefix="R$ " />
```

Comment: Obrigado, era isso que eu estava procurando :)

Comment: Fui aplicar a função no meu código hoje, porém estou usando EditorFor do asp.net-mvc e os dados de **data-thousands="." data-decimal="," data-prefix="R$ "** não são reconhecidos, como poderia fazer? Esta é a linha de código: **@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Salario, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control",id="meudinheiro" } })**

Comment: para o input type funciona, mas usando EditorFor não

Comment: Já resolvi aqui... no link que deixou, tem o formato... Valeu