# Mascara Javascript

Tags: javascript

Boa tarde pessoal, preciso de uma ajuda de vocês.

Eu preciso de uma mascara para um campo numero em meu sistema, onde o usuário pode digitar de 0,0 até 130,00 caso o valor seja maior que 130 só ira aceitar 999,99.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Pergunta: você pode utilizar jQuery no seu projeto? Pois aí poderia ser aplicado jQuery.mask que é uma funcionalidade do jQuery bastante útil pro teu problema. Caso não possa verei uma solução nativa.

Comment: Você quer que valide ou que limite para 3 digitos antes da virgula?

Answer (score 2):

Basta aplicar `maxlength` contando todos os caracteres em `999,99`, que no caso seria `6`, basicamente daria para aplicar o `maxlength` para quase qualquer mascara que você encontrar.

Claro que alguns plugins jQuery e afins já tem configuração pra isto, mas são exceções.

Exemplos de mascaras monetárias/dinheiro que existem no site:

### Com jQuery:

- Resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/164995/3635

```js
$("#meuDinheiro").maskMoney();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://plentz.github.io/jquery-maskmoney/javascripts/jquery.maskMoney.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="meuDinheiro" data-thousands="." data-decimal="," data-prefix="" maxlength="6" />
```

Agora se deseja que vire `999,99` pode limitar para `7` e aplicar `keyup`

```js
$("#meuDinheiro").maskMoney().on("keyup", function () {
   if (this.value.length > 6) {
       this.value = "999,99";
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://plentz.github.io/jquery-maskmoney/javascripts/jquery.maskMoney.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="meuDinheiro" data-thousands="." data-decimal="," data-prefix="" maxlength="7" />
```

---

### Sem jQuery (JavaScript e Regex)

Da resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/241646/3635

```js
function formatarMoeda() {
  var elemento = document.getElementById('valor');
  var valor = elemento.value;
  
  valor = valor + '';
  valor = parseInt(valor.replace(/[\D]+/g,''));

  if (!isNaN(valor)) {
    valor = valor + '';
    valor = valor.replace(/([0-9]{2})$/g, ",$1");

    if (valor.length > 6) {
        valor = valor.replace(/([0-9]{3}),([0-9]{2}$)/g, ".$1,$2");
    }
  } else {
     valor = '';
  }

  elemento.value = valor;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="valor" onkeyup="formatarMoeda();" maxlength="6" />
```

Agora se deseja que vire `999,99` pode limitar para `7` e aplicar `keyup`

```js
function formatarMoeda() {
  var elemento = document.getElementById('valor');
  var valor = elemento.value;
  
  valor = valor + '';
  valor = parseInt(valor.replace(/[\D]+/g,''));

  if (!isNaN(valor)) {
    valor = valor + '';
    valor = valor.replace(/([0-9]{2})$/g, ",$1");

    if (valor.length > 6) {
        valor = '999,99'; //Mudei esta linha
    }
  } else {
     valor = '';
  }

  elemento.value = valor;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="valor" onkeyup="formatarMoeda();" maxlength="7" />
```

Comment: Pelo que entendi, na verdade, pode qualquer valor entre 0.00 e 130.00 e caso ultrapasse 130.00 todos os valores serão invalidos até que chegue ao valor 999.99

Comment: @PauloRoberto agora fiquei na duvida também.

Comment: Tbm compreendi conforme o @Paulo disse.

Comment: @PauloRoberto é isso mesmo, se o valor passar de 130,00 o campo tem que ficar 999,99

Comment: @LeonardoMacedo não acho muito pratico pro usuário ficar modificando o valor, mas editei a resposta e adicionei dois exemplos

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimentoP. Peço desculpas cara a minha duvida é totalmente diferente, como estou mexendo em um sistema que é webforms, estou tendo uma certa dificuldade em entender os códios, mais eu irei abrir um outro tópico explicando melhor o que realmente preciso de ajuda

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimentoP.
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/263951/exce%C3%A7%C3%A3o-para-um-campo-webforms está seria realmente a minha duvida