# erro de formatação tipo moeda em jquery

Tags: jquery

Estou criando uma máscara no meu campo assim:

```
$("#ValorMultaSt").mask('000.000.000,00', { reverse: true });
```

Quando eu digito algum valor funciona perfeitamente, porém quando executo qualquer ação na tela ele coloca um "." na frente, como no exemplo:

Se eu digito `444,44` após executar uma ação na tela o valor é alterado para `.444,44`

Função javascript:

```
function AtualizarMascaras() {
            // Mascaras
            $("#ValorPorcentagemField").mask('000', { reverse: true });
            $("#ValorMultaSt").mask('000.000.000,00', { reverse: true });
            $("#ValorMultaAcrescimoSt").mask('000.000.000,00', { reverse: true });
            $("#ValorMultaFaixaMinimaSt").mask('000.000.000,00', { reverse: true });
            $("#ValorMultaFaixaMaximaSt").mask('000.000.000,00', { reverse: true });
            $("#DataPublicacao").mask('00/00/0000');
        }
```

Função que chama a função de Atualizar máscara:

```
$(function () {           

            $(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
                AtualizarMascaras();
            });

            AtualizarMascaras();
});
```

Div html do campo:

```
<div class="row" id="divValorMulta">
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ValorMultaSt, "Valor da Multa")
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ValorMultaSt, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", disabled, @placeholder = "R$" } })
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Alguem consegue me ajudar?

Comment: Utilize o plugin Jquery-maskMoney. Veja [Aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/164990/mascara-para-valores-monet%C3%A1rios)

Comment: Que "ação" seria essa?

Comment: nao, ja removi e continua o mesmo erro

Comment: Em que momento esse código é executado? Poste esse trecho também, na sua pergunta. Que tipo de ação faz com que o valor seja alterado de forma incorreta?

Comment: Qualquer ação que faça submit na tela....

Comment: "reverse: true"  é para colocar a máscara da direita para a esquerda.

Comment: Tenta simular aqui ou no jsfiddle.

Comment: @Netinho Santos, ja removi, o erro permanece...

Comment: Não é o "reverse: true" que está causando o erro. Como falei, ele é para colocar a máscara da direita para a esquerda. Tente simular aqui colocando o código completo.

Comment: postei o codigo completo...

Comment: Posta o HTML já renderizado no navegador. `CTRL + U`

Comment: <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="ValorMultaSt" name="ValorMultaSt" placeholder="R$" type="text" value=" 333,33" maxlength="14" autocomplete="off">

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar outro plugin voltado especificamente para mascaras de moeda.  [MaskMoney](https://github.com/plentz/jquery-maskmoney)

Seu código ficaria da seguinte maneira.

```
function AtualizarMascaras() {
            // Mascaras
        $("#ValorPorcentagemField").maskMoney({prefix:'R$ ', allowNegative: true, thousands:'.', decimal:',', affixesStay: false});
        $("#ValorMultaSt").maskMoney({prefix:'R$ ', allowNegative: true, thousands:'.', decimal:',', affixesStay: false});
        $("#ValorMultaAcrescimoSt").maskMoney({prefix:'R$ ', allowNegative: true, thousands:'.', decimal:',', affixesStay: false});
        $("#ValorMultaFaixaMinimaSt").maskMoney({prefix:'R$ ', allowNegative: true, thousands:'.', decimal:',', affixesStay: false});
        $("#ValorMultaFaixaMaximaSt").maskMoney({prefix:'R$ ', allowNegative: true, thousands:'.', decimal:',', affixesStay: false});
        $("#DataPublicacao").maskMoney({prefix:'R$ ', allowNegative: true, thousands:'.', decimal:',', affixesStay: false});
        }
```

Comment: obrigado, deu certo.